# Basic, putting select option by a choose from an another select

Tags: javascript

```
</head>
      <body>
         <fieldset>
                <legend>D'où venez-vous ?</legend>
             <div>Pays:
            <select id="pays">
                    <option value="1">Canada</option>       
                    <option value="1">France</option>       
            </select>       

        </div>
              <div>Ville:<select id="ville"onclick="myFunction()"> 
 </select>   
           </div>

             </fieldset>
          </body>
     </html>
```

Basically, what I want to do is to put option on my second select called '' ville '', When i choose Canada it will give me 3 city from that other select and vice versa for France. I'm not sure how to do this exercice. thanks. Should I use a for, or only if else conditions could work.

Comment: How are you getting the list of cities for the selected country? Perhaps you could show us some of the javascript code you have in place?

Comment: Without see your js code - start by changing onclick to onchange.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution:

```js
// Setting variables which cannot be redeclared
const pays = document.getElementById('pays');
const france = ['Paris', 'Lyon', 'Marseille'];
const canada = ['Toronto', 'Vancouver', 'Victoria'];

// If select element (#pays) changes
pays.addEventListener('change', () => {
  // France
  if (pays.value === 'France') {
    createElement(france);
  }
  // Canada
  else if (pays.value === 'Canada') {
    createElement(canada);
  }
});

// Create option elements
function createElement(country) {
  const ville = document.getElementById('ville');
  // Delete all values before adding new ones
  ville.innerHTML = '';

  // Use a loop for the array called "country"
  country.forEach((e) => {
    // Setting variables which could be redeclared within a block
    let option = document.createElement('option');
    let text = document.createTextNode(e);
    // Appen the element with text
    option.appendChild(text);
    ville.appendChild(option);
  })
}
```

```html
<select id="pays">
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>       
  <option value="France">France</option>       
</select>

<select id="ville">
```

Comment: what is the  const? is it like var? also could you explain to me what do you there at country.forEach((e)

Comment: @EngjëllBislimi I have edited my answer and added some comments, so you understand.

Comment: @EngjëllBislimi your welcome. If it helped you, please mark this answer as solved.